# Keeping selected tree view element on the screen (like Windows Explorer)

Tags: angular, treeview, angular7

I've made a very basic tree view in Angular 7. I basically have an array of objects, where I can select an item and use the arrow keys to select the next. Problem is, I want this to behave close to the Windows Explorer, so that if I scroll to the last element in the `overflow:auto` div, the next element (which is not on the screen) should be shown when I scroll to it. In my Angular example below, it simply selects the element out of the screen.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eavqd6

The selected element is simply based on the:

```
public selected: string;
```

which I simply increase or decrease depending on the arrow key pushed. I then add a `selected` class to the element by doing:

```
class="{{item.ordering == selected ? 'selected' : ''}}"
```

If I wanted to scroll the selected element into view, I've been thinking about using the [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function, but I'm not quite sure if it's efficient when it comes to performance (nor how I would implement it).

I could give each element an unique ID, which would hopefully speed up the performance, but I'm not sure if it is efficient enough.

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to give each item an ID; you can give the container an ID, and then select the items using the index.

If you access the container div, like so:

```
<div #container>
  <p *ngFor="let item of list" class="{{item.ordering == selected ? 'selected' : ''}}">{{item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

And in the component:

```
@ViewChild("container")
public container: ElementRef;
```

You can then create a function that uses the `selected` property to find the relevant item:

```
private scroll() {
    const elm = this.container.nativeElement.children[this.selected - 1];
    if (elm) {
      elm.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

**[Here is an example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klqsnp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Very interesting approach! Calling `.nativeElement`, does that also work for children? A tree view generally has multiple levels, so it should work with that as well. Also, it should only scroll to the element, if it's out of the screen (but I guess it's easy to check that)

Comment: You only need to call `.nativeElement` on the `ElementRef`. Once you've done that there's no need to call `.nativeElement`, because it's already a `nativeElement` if that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I think we're missing each others point haha. I was asking if `.nativeElement.children` also grabs the children's children. If you picture a tree view (like this: https://infinite-tree.js.org/examples.html) you can see it has multiple layers. In my example, I simply have a bunch of ul>li tags (to create the nested tree view). That infinite-tree page also does exactly what I want

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, when you call `.children`, it will return an array of nodes, and each node will also have a `children` property, recursively. Does that help?

Comment: For large trees, that might be an issue. Our trees can have a couple of thousand elements, so calling it recursively would definitely cost a lot of resources. I have all my jobs in a "dictionary" (id,job) if that makes more sense. So basically all root elements and all their children are in an object, where the key is the id of the job and the value is the actual job. That way I can do a O(1) lookup, if that helps

Comment: Okay, I have updated my Angular project to reflect basically what I have in my working environment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eavqd6 - My jobs now have children and so on. Going up the tree is currently not supported, because it's kind of useless in this example.